# how can I get Instagram photos to save to my SD card?

Tags: external-sd, instagram

I have Instagram and I like saving the pictures that I take, but they're taking up tons of space in my internal storage. I have a nice big SD card for storage, and have my phone set up to save all the regular pictures I take with the camera to the SD card, but I can't figure out how to get the Instagram pictures to save there as well.  Anybody have any luck with this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried moving the app itself to the SD card? Maybe it's not the photos, but the internal cache that's taking up all your storage.

Anyway, according to [Instagram Help](http://help.instagram.com/186754094794097):

> The Android app may take up more internal memory than other apps on your device because we cache photos, which makes the Instagram experience faster for you and conserves bandwidth (which means you don't have to re-download photos over your carrier's network). Note that as of v1.0.3, you can install the app on your device's SD card.
>
> On Android, you can find out how much space Instagram takes up on your device by following these steps:
>
> 1. Exit Instagram
> 2. Open the Settings application on your device > Applications > Manage applications > Instagram
> 3. Total Storage is listed on the Instagram screen.
>
> If you choose Clear data, your download cache will be cleared. Clear cache will reset memory for the app.

There is not, otherwise, a way to tell Instagram to store your photos directly to your SD card.

Comment: I believe he / she didn't mean the cached one. it's the cropped-square picture instagram save after you crop the image in the instagram.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into Storage --> Navigate to Instagram -----> click on "Change" next to "stored in" and you can switch where instagram stores data, I switched mine from internal to SD card, on my galaxy s5.

Comment: That must be a Samsung setting. No such setting exists on my Pixel.